# Does "while" need a comma for this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The sentence:

- I demonstrated great multitasking skills in a housing hall with 500 students, while still providing friendly customer service.

Also, is the sentence to clunky?

I am trying to show that I worked for the largest housing hall on campus and exhibited great multitasking skills all while providing friendly customer service.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *while* does not need a comma before it, as it acts as a subordinating conjunction (the clause that follows, "still providing customer service," isn't grammatical on its own; moreover, it doesn't make much sense outside the context of the first clause - you're clearly using it to describe *how* you managed the housing hall, making it an adverb clause). In general, subordinating conjunctions don't require the comma before the conjunction if they're attached to the end of the independent clause. On the other hand, I most often see a "while" clause with a comma beforehand when trying to emphasize a contrast: "Mike went to Store X, while Dave went to Store Y" or "Jennie likes merlot, while Charlotte prefers Pabst Blue Ribbon." You're not contrasting here, so it's a good bet the comma isn't necessary.

As for the sentence as a whole, I might actually add the word "managing" to the first clause, as in:

"I demonstrated great multitasking skills in *managing* a housing hall with 500 students while still providing friendly customer service."

To me, that simply makes it abundantly explicit what it was you were doing in multitasking in a position at a housing hall. If you find it poorly suited to your actual responsibilities in that job, the sentence is fine on its own. Whether the sentence is too clunky is somewhat more subjective. This sentence sounds perfectly reasonable to my (native English-speaker) ear.

Comment: Actually, I think adding "managing" (or something like it) is valuable here, because without it what it really says is that you "demonstrated multitasking skills" while at the same time "providing friendly customer service" (i.e. providing customer service was not part of your multitasking skills, it was something separate).  However, with "managing" in that position, it says that the *skills you were multitasking* included both "managing the housing hall" and "providing customer service", which I suspect is more what was intended.